# Getting warning "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" while making window root view controller in app delegate?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the code

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeTBC") as! UITabBarController
self.window?.rootViewController = vc
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

cant figure it yet.

Comment: You should give the right size

Comment: size for what ? actually i am making here UItabbar controller as windows root and in story board i have navigation controller containing relation segue with tab bar controller and a home vc containing relation segue i.e is root view controller for navigation,,..

Comment: For the `UIWindow`

Comment: tried but still same warning..

Comment: Can you add a picture? And we'll see your vc's relationship

Comment: @Mannopson [link] (https://imgur.com/IQbkVja)

Comment: Make your tab bar controller as an initial view controller using storyboard. Why do you need to change the window itself? What is the your goal? I don't understand

Comment: Actully first i have to login user.. after login tabbar will appear user is already logged in then i used tabbar  as rootViewController of window.

Comment: If I correctly understand, you have a two storyboards right?

Comment: no i have one story board.. login vc is set as initial vc. now if the user is not logged in previously then automatically login vc will present and if user enter his credentials in the past then this code will run based on a flag saved in user defaults.

Comment: If so? You shouldn't change the window. It's better to use with the two storyboards. You can easily switch storyboards when your App finishing launches

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow)

> When creating windows, always set the window’s initial size and
>   specify the screen on which it is displayed.

Add the size:

```
self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

Your complete code should be like that:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeTBC") as! UITabBarController
self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = vc
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: @junaidUmer Remove `UINavigationController` and make your tab bar controller as an initial vc. It's just works

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this code in My App for root view controller in app delegate working perfect:

As I think you are using this code in presented view controller or in presented navigation controller: Please send the scenario(Screen Shot) exact what you are doing?

```
    var window: UIWindow?
    window =  UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarVC") as! TabbarVC
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: (https://imgur.com/IQbkVja) this is what i am doing in storyBoard and in app delegate just the above code

Comment: Please send the demo code on my email I will do. or please send me the video of storyboard & file. I want to see  what exactly and where you are doing this.

Comment: spandey211@gmail.com